# Windows OS's cannot boot on new internal harddrive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, laptop

I have installed a new internal 500GB hard drive into a Dell Inspiron N4030 and it appears that the installation was entirely successful. The BIOS recognizes the drive and shows the serial number of the hard drive.

The problem is that I cannot boot any Windows OS. I have tried XP, Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8. It displays only a black screen with a blinking cursor. Fedora boots successfully. My old hard drive crashed, but would atleast boot up these OS's before it died.

Any help?

Comment: That is the most baffling problem I have ever heard of

Comment: If I encountered this problem then the partition with windows wasn't marked as "active".

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows boot Windows partition is must be as active, that's right but after it was not worked well in my case. A new hard drive was installed in another laptop and it boot successfull. It works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try a partition tool, to be able to configure Windows partition as Active.
It is easier to install Windows first, and then Linux, to avoid having MBR created by Linux.
Try entering the disk utility before installing Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For windows boot Windows partition is must be as active, that's right but after it was not worked well in my case.
A new hard drive was installed in another laptop and it boot successfull.
It works in my case.